# _id is given None after saving data into model Mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

i tried to save data into mongodb database using Mongoengine orm and flask, the problem is whene i save data then try to access data from saved object its given none

here is my view.py

```
s = Users(name="kaushik")
s.username = "kaushikmakwana"
data = s.save()
print(s) # output users object
print(data._id) #output None
print(data.id) #outeput None
```

here is my model.py

```
class Users(DynamicDocument):

    meta = {'collection' : 'user'}

    _id = StringField()
    name = StringField()
    username = StringField()
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Users %r' % self.name
```

why its give None? how can i access this object data after saved?

Comment: You should get data in "s" object. "data" would contain the return value of s.save() operation, which seems None. So, print(s._id) would give you the right value.

Comment: thanks @abhay i tried your solution but its still give None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete _id from your model, this field is autogenerated from mongodb

Comment: Thnks a lot osmay88 :)